# Proof Verification of $B \cup A = B$ implies $Pr(A) \leq Pr(B)$

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

**Basic Information**

If you're confused $Pr(A)$ stand for probability of A.

**My Work**

1) $A\cup B = B \iff A \subseteq B$ (By Theorem 3.4 in our textbook)

2) $A \subseteq B \implies |A| \leq |B|$

*Proof of Step 2:*

A can be a strict subset ($\subseteq$) or a proper subset ($\subset$). If A is a strict subset of B that means |A| = |B|. If A is a proper subset of B, all elements of A are in B, and some elements of B are not in A. Therefore, |B| = |A| + extra. This means |A| < |B|. Therefore, |A| $\leq |B|$.

3) $|A| \leq |B| \implies Pr(|A|) \leq Pr(|B|) \iff Pr(A) \leq Pr(B)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to involve cardinality. By definition of probability, $A\subseteq B \implies P(A)\leq P(B)$ if $P(A),P(B)$ both exist.

Note, from probability axioms and the assumption $B\cup A = B$:

$P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)=P(B) \implies P(A)=P(A\cap B)\leq P(B)$

The last step comes about because the probability of an intersection can be no greater than the probably of either set involved in the intersection.

Comment: How does that implication work without using cardinality?

Comment: @Dunka a probability is a type of measure, and hence exhibits monotonicity. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)#Monotonicity.

Comment: @Dunka the proof is very straightforward. I edited my post.